# Add data series to highlight cases on a box plot (Excel, SPSS or R)

Tags: spss, excel, boxplot

first time user of this forum - guidance on how to provide enough information is very appreciated. I am trying to replicate the presentation of data used in the Medical education field. This will help improve the quality of examiners' marking of trainees in a Clinical Exam. What I would like to communicate will be similar to what is already communicated in the College of General Practitioners regarding one of their own exams, please see www.gp10.com.au/slides/thursday/slide29.pdf to help understand what it is I want to present. I have access to Excel, SPSS and R, so any help with any of these would be great. However as a first attempt I have used SPSS and created 3 variables: dummy variable, a "station score" and a "global rating score"(GRS). The "station score"(ST) is a value between 0 and 10 (non-integers) and is on the y-axis similar to the pdf presentation of "Candidate Final Marks". The x-axis is the "global rating scale", an integer from 1 to 6 and is represented in the pdf as the "Overall Performance Scale". When I use SPSS's boxplot I get a boxplot as depicted.

[image: Boxplot ST vs GRS].

What I would like to do is overlay a single examiners own scoring of X number of examinees. So for one examiner (examiner A) provided the following marks:
ST: 5.53,7.38,7.38,7.44,6.81
GRS: 3,4,4,5,3
(this is transposed into two columns).

Whether it be SPSS, Excel or R how would I be able to overlay the box and whisker plots with the individual data points provided by the one examiner?  This would help show the degree to which the examiners' marking styles are in concordance with the expected distribution of ST scores across GRS. Any help greatly appreciated! I like Excel graphics but I have found it very difficult to work with when choosing the examiners' data as a separate series - somehow the examiners' GRS scores do not line up nicely on the x-axis. I am very new to R but am also very interested in R, and would expend time to get a good result in R if a good result is viable. I understand JMP may be preferable for this type of thing but access to this may not be possible.

Comment: I've seen this question for SPSS a few times, so I went ahead and wrote a [blog post](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/repeating-charts-in-spss-for-unique-ids/) on how to do it using python. If python is not an option [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=db66a899-e0d1-44b7-a151-da6dbd79bff3&ps=25) I provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for getting back so quickly. I will check those solutions out!